# Receiving a core dumped while using flex-bison and cpp

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I am using flex-bison to make a basic compiler of an invented language for an appointment. The problem is that I always receive a core dumped error when I test the 'continue' sentence. I know this might be more a cpp problem than flex-bison problem.

```
| RCONTINUE TSEMIC
    {
    $$ = new sentenciastruct;
vector<int> tmp;
tmp.push_back(codigo.obtenRef());
$$->conti = tmp;
    codigo.anadirInstruccion("goto"); 
    }
```

This is the 'problematic' part, if i comment the push back line, the error does not appear but the compiler does not do what it is supposed to. (all the functions of codigo are supposed to be okay because they are given by the teachers).

It looks like, in other rules of the grammar, the $$->conti vector just disapperars giving the error.

The conti value is mainly used in here, it is a vector of references to uncomplete goto instructions in the generated code:

```
| RWHILE M expresion TDOSPT M bloque M 
    {
    codigo.anadirInstruccion("goto");
    vector<int> *tmp1 = new vector<int>; 
tmp1->push_back($7) ;
    codigo.completarInstrucciones(*tmp1, $2) ;
    }
    RELSE TDOSPT bloque M
    {
    $$ = new sentenciastruct;
    codigo.completarInstrucciones($3->trues,$5);
    codigo.completarInstrucciones($3->falses,$7 + 1);
    codigo.completarInstrucciones($6->exit,$7 + 1);
    codigo.completarInstrucciones($6->conti,$2);
    codigo.completarInstrucciones($11->exit,$12);
    codigo.completarInstrucciones($11->conti,$2);
    delete $3;
    }
```

The struct that contains the conti vector is the following:

```
struct sentenciastruct {
vector<int> exit;
vector<int> conti;
};
```

I have tried many ways to initialize the conti vector on the rule I mentioned before but none of them worked.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out your problem.

Comment: Using a debugger might help, too. What do you mean by "It looks like, in other rules of the grammar, the `$$->conti` vector just disappears giving the error." What is the evidence which leads you to that conclusion? (And why didn't you include that data in your original post?)

Comment: Check what object's reference is `codigo.obtenRef()` returning and the lifetime of that object. BTW you do not need a temporary `tmp`vector (you can spare a construction copy), you can `push_back` directly to the newly created struct: `$$->conti.push_back(codigo.obtenRef());`